# How exactly Cassandra read procedure works?

Tags: performance, cassandra

I have a little experience with cassandra But I have one query regarding cassandra read process.

Suppose we have 7 sstables for a given table in our cassandra db now If we perform any read query which is not cached in memtable So Cassandra will look into the sstables. My question is:-

During this process will cassandra load all the sstables(7) into the memtable or It will just look into the all the sstables and will load relevant rows in memtable instead of loading all the sstables ?

Thanking you in advance!!
And please do correct me If I have interpreted something wrong.

And It also would be great If some one can explain/mention better resources to know about working of sstables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> During this process will cassandra load all the sstables(7)

No. Cassandra wouldn't load all the 7 `SSTables`. Each `SSTable` has a `BloomFilter` (in-memory) that tells the possibility for having the data in that `SSTable`.

If BloomFilter indicates a possibility of having the data in the SSTable, it looks into the `partition key cache` and gets the `compression offset map` (in-memory) to retrieve the compressed block that has the data we are looking for.

- If found in the partition key cache, then the compressed block is read (I/O) to get the data.
- If not found, it looks into partition summary to get the location of index entry and reads that location (I/O) into memory and continues with compression offset map flow earlier.

To start with, this [Cassandra Reads](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_reads_c.html) link I think should help and depicts the flow pictorially. Capturing below the read path from above link for quick reference.

[image: Cassandra Read path]

And one more thing, there is also a row cache which contains the hot rows (accessed frequently) and this will not result in hitting/loading the SSTable if found in the `row cache`.

Go through this [rowcache](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_how_cache_works_c.html) link to understand row cache and partition key cache.

Another great presentation shared by Jeff Jirsa, [Understanding Cassandra Table Options](http://www.slideshare.net/JeffJirsa1/alter-table-with-understanding-cassandra-table-options). Really worth going through it.

On a different note, there is `compaction` the happens periodically to reduce the number of SSTables and delete the rows based on `tombstones`.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks Aaron. Glad you liked my answer :)

Comment: This answer is great, so rather than re-answering it, I'm adding on to note that a lot of these actions are configurable (bloom filter accuracy, index thresholds, compression chunk sizes) - Talked about many of them at a recent C* meetup: http://www.slideshare.net/JeffJirsa1/alter-table-with-understanding-cassandra-table-options

Comment: @JeffJirsa Thanks for sharing the link. Slides are awesome. I have added to the answer as it would really help the user community.